# Making unit conversion app, can't get number pad when I click text field

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Hi I'm new to swift and I was wondering how to display a number pad when I click the text field. I want a text field to get user input from a number pad and convert that cm value to inches. [This is what it's showing on simulator so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekoNs.png) All the examples I found online didn't work.. I feel like I'm getting this error because I'm using shared variables in AppDelegate.swift

So this is what I have so far:

```swift
//AppDelegate.swift
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    //Variables being shared
    var cmValue:Double = 1.0

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }

    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }


}
```

```swift
//FirstViewController.swift
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var dataTextField: UITextField!

    //make object so that we can access AppDelegate
    let ap = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    //called when printing page
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        //set shared variable value to text field
        dataTextField.text = String(ap.cmValue)
    }

    @IBAction func tapInput() {
        //exit keyboard
        if let text = dataTextField.text {
            //if there is a value in text field
            if let cmValue = Double(text) {
                ap.cmValue = cmValue 
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }




}
```

Comment: "All the examples I found online didn't work" Didn't work how? What does that mean? "I feel like I'm getting this error" What error? You have forgotten to tell us what the problem is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to show the keyboard in simulator, when you press inside the textfield, hit command+k to show the keyboard to see which keyboard your textfield is using. if you want to change the keyboard type, just change the keyboard type property on the textfield

something like this:

```
dataTextField.keyboardType = .numberPad
```

Comment: i remember when i first started and couldn't figure this out either, it's okay, glad i could help :)